# Button Touch State in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, uibutton

I want to know the state of button when is pressed and when user remove the finger from Button like in JavaScript there are events OnKeyDown and show a alert onKeyup show another alert in iOS I looking for some thing like JavaScript i found touchupInside(ONkeyDown) touchupOutside(OnkeyUp) but i cant log any thing when button is up (mean user remove his/her fingure from button ) is this possible in ios i looking some thing like that

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = ![button isSelected]; // Important line
if (button.selected)
{
    NSLog(@"Selected");
    NSLog(@"%i",button.tag);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Un Selected");
    NSLog(@"%i",button.tag);

}
```

Comment: TouchupInside/touchUpOutside are actually called when the button finger is lifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what u need is different control events `OnKeyDown` event as soon as button is tapped for this u need `UIControlEventTouchDown` event and for `onKeyup` u need `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` by using these two events for button u can get what u want for example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 100)];
  [button setTitle:@"Touch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onKeyupEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onKeyDownEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [self.view addSubview:button];
 }

 - (void)onKeyupEvent:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"key up event");
}

- (void)onKeyDownEvent:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"key down event");
}
```

Comment: i did like this i dont know witch one is best     [myButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    - (void)touchEnded:(UIButton *)addOnButton withEvent:event {
    NSLog(@"button Released.....");
}   its working fine too

Comment: u decide , if u want different events to be occurred , then use my example or else use yours

Comment: by the way in your example in the comment only `onKeyup` event will get not the `keyDown` event

Comment: yeah correct actually i m doing key down through story board so simply connect IBAction to that button on Touch Down  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are number of events that you can make use of, and you'll be able to find the whole list by googling `UIControl Class Reference`. Take a look at `control events` in the `constant` section.

Also, you can trigger these events by doing something like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then add the following method:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonEvent:(id)sender {
    // do something...
}
```